# Can't hide the link "how to embed google map" under the map in my website

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I can't hide the link "how to embed google map" under the map in my website.

```
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyD0kdWVIPpFGdRWTTakMpe-GFsgOXnr0JQ'></script>
<div style='overflow:hidden;height:400px;width:100%;'>
   <div id='gmap_canvas' style='height:400px;width:100%;'></div
       <style>#gmap_canvas img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important}</style>
</div>
<a href='https://www.embed-map.net/'>how to embed google map</a> <script type='text/javascript' src='https://embedmaps.com/google-maps-authorization/script.js?id=b9034e5a46df59aa59d9407a13d18c82efa4b408'></script><script type='text/javascript'>
function init_map() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.657185, 23.364427699999965),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(42.657185, 23.364427699999965)
    });
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: '<strong>Авантюрин</strong><br>Илия Димушев<br>1756 Sofia<br>'
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
```

I tried to delete this element:

```
 <a href='https://www.embed-map.net/'>how to embed google map</a>
```

Tried to hide it with display:none; But it hides the whole map. Any ideas how to remove this?

Comment: you are using a 3rd party code generator if you see in your linked js https://embedmaps.com/google-maps-authorization/script.js?id=b9034e5a46df59aa59d9407a13d18c82efa4b408 it checks for the anchor tag probably it an branding thing if you still wanna remove it either get that code in local and by pass that check or can set the style to display none after the map loads https://plnkr.co/edit/wMaEPizQo2wQ5CjQjfZP?p=preview

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, you are missing the closing `>` on this line: `<div id='gmap_canvas' style='height:400px;width:100%;'></div` and you are missing the closing `</script>` tag.  [When I fix those, I can remove the embed line (fiddle).](http://jsfiddle.net/xv0rv9qp/3/)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code:**

```
<script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=AIzaSyD0kdWVIPpFGdRWTTakMpe-GFsgOXnr0JQ'></script><div style='overflow:hidden;height:400px;width:100%;'><div id='gmap_canvas' style='height:400px;width:100%;'></div><style>#gmap_canvas img{max-width:none!important;background:none!important}</style></div> <script type='text/javascript' src='https://embedmaps.com/google-maps-authorization/script.js?id=b9034e5a46df59aa59d9407a13d18c82efa4b408'></script><script type='text/javascript'>function init_map(){var myOptions = {zoom:15,center:new google.maps.LatLng(42.657185,23.364427699999965),mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), myOptions);marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(42.657185,23.364427699999965)});infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content:'<strong>Авантюрин</strong><br>Илия Димушев<br>1756 Sofia<br>'});google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){infowindow.open(map,marker);});infowindow.open(map,marker);}google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
</script>
```